# Why does my nvidia graphics card in combination with XFCE compositor have poor performance?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xubuntu, xfce

I have a fancy (for my standards) graphics card, NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1060.

Xubuntu used to work very well. Since upgrades to, I think 19.04, and also the recent 20.04, the overall experience is lagging, which manifests itself in a flickering display, and slow responsiveness. The framerate seems to be lower. Hard to quantify or describe more precisely, but I can notice it without doubt. When I try to increase the framerate in Display settings, this makes no difference.

When I switch off XFCE compositor in Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks, the experience returns to normal.

However on my several years older laptop with simple Intel graphics, XFCE works fine with compositing, so this solution is suboptimal to me.

I tried using the nouveau open source display driver (which only gives 1024x768 resolution) and earlier versions of the NVIDIA proprietary driver (no success). But perhaps this has more to do with recent changes to the XFCE compositor than to the NVIDIA driver?

Comment: My recommendation is to dump the compositor in Xfce4 and go with Compton instead.  It is what I use and work great with Xubuntu (Xfce4)  http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/07/how-to-switch-to-compton-for-beautiful-tear-free-compositing-in-xfce/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I looked into it but got scared but didn't feel like adding ppa's to my fresh Xubuntu install yet. In fact I googled a bit more on the XFCE compositor and found this link: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=13233.

Comment: (premature end of comment): following the suggestioon of restarting xfwm4 with option vblank_mode=off seems to significantly improve the situation.

Comment: Actually, Compton is now in the default Ubuntu repositories.  `apt-cache madison compton`  returns `compton | 0.1~beta2+20150922-1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages`  But the rest of the link is good for settings in Compton.  And now that I think about it, I did not install from a 3rd party repo last time I set it up.  I just installed it and configured it.

Comment: @Terrance: yes, that works, simply installing (apt install compton) and then running compton also gives good results.